# How to implement a scenario in Gherkin where a conditional is required?

Tags: gherkin, scenarios, user-stories

I am business analyst/ PO who is trying to utilize Gherkin for the first time. I have the following scenario (and mostly these types only) where the expected behavior is:

Given I a registered user
And I am on a landing page
When I select an option to...(say search and connect with my client agent)
Then the system prompts me to turn on geo location (thru my app)

Now based on the accept or deny for the above prompt, the system presents different screens for a user to move forward. If I accept, system displays map and specific search. If I deny, system displays another way to search.

How do I implement such a scenario?

Comment: This is community site, using words such `urgent` will not help in any way

Comment: thanks rkosegi. But would have helped more if you could have provided an additional help as well :)...Though will keep in mind.

Comment: Downvote: Can you please refrain from using "urgent" to boost the importance of that post? I would recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Done guys. But some one still pls respond with an solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 'if' in Gherkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434613/how-to-implement-if-in-gherkin)

Comment: Also possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233391/does-if-else-concept-available-in-feature-file-gherkin-language

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a split, where two differing outcomes can happen.
They are separate scenarios.

The first, you are looking for a prompt. The second, confirm, and check outcomes, the third, deny and check outcomes.

```
Background: 
  Given I a registered user
   And I am on a landing page
  When I select an option to search and connect with my client agent

Scenario: I should be prompted
  Then the app should prompt me to turn on geo-location

Scenario: I turn on my geo-location
  When I turn on my geo-location
  Then I should see a map
  And I should see a specific search

Scenario: I turn off my geo-location
  When I deny the app access to my geo-location
  Then I should see another way to search
```